# Android tri-color gradient

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, kotlin

I would like to set the background of my android application to a tri-color gradient. I have tried the following line of code:

`binding.splashScreenRelativeLayout.background = gradient`

Where binding is the data binding variable to my XML layout and gradient is

`gradient = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR, intArrayOf(startColor, midColor, endColor))`.

I have also tried creating a custom drawable class and using it as an XML element but without any success as I haven't found much documentation using XML with custom drawables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to create a drawable resource file? You can create an shape and inside of that you can set a gradient with start, center and end color, like this:

```
    <shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</shape>
```

then you'll have a tricolored gradient. Now all you gonna do is setting this as background of your layout file.

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity, is there a way that I could set a background with kotlin as I attempted to do above? Additionally are there any references that I can look at to learn how I can create a custom XML drawable? i.e using something like <com.example.MyDrawable> instead of <gradient>

Comment: Hey, man. There's no need to use code to set a drawable as background. You can do it using xml directly, just go to the editor and add the attribute like android:background="@drawable/gradient"

Comment: But you can do this by code. IDK how to do it in kotlin, because I use java. But probably there's a guide for it.